# How To Set CAGradientLayer to CAShapeLayer Without Frame

Tags: ios, core-animation, core-graphics

Hello i am working with core animation and core graphics.I am drawing one path which is not rectangle or circle or ellipse so i cant give frame to that path.Now i want to set gradient colour to path.But for that i need frame,that i cant give.Here is code for my path :

```
CGPoint point1 = CGPointMake(120.0f, 50.0f);
CGPoint point2 = CGPointMake(240.0f, 150.0f);
CGPoint point3 = CGPointMake(360.0f, 50.0f);
CGPoint point4 = CGPointMake(480.0f+50/2.0, 100.0f);

CGMutablePathRef curvedPath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, 50, 50);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, point1.x, 50, point1.x, 50, point1.x, point1.y);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, point2.x, 50, point2.x, 50, point2.x, point2.y);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, point3.x, 50, point3.x, 50, point3.x, point3.y);
CGPathAddCurveToPoint(curvedPath, NULL, point4.x, 50, point4.x, 50, point4.x, point4.y);
CGPathCloseSubpath(curvedPath);
return curvedPath;
```

Comment: i want simply top to bottom gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CGPathGetPathBoundingBox`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000959-CH1g-CGPathGetBoundingBox).  If `gradientLayer` is a sublayer or mask layer of `shapeLayer`, try this:

```
gradientLayer.frame = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(shapeLayer.path);
```